# http\Client->enqueue(http\Client\Request)->send() resets connection to the server PHP

Tags: php, apache

I've just installed the module pecl_http 2.5.1 on my server, and I am attempting to send a get request to a different port of my site (which requires https) from the following php script:

```
if(!isset($_POST['user']) || !isset($_POST['pass']) || $_POST['user']=="" || $_POST['pass']=="")
{   
    header("Location:https://MY_IP:444/");
    exit;
}

require_once("contants.php");
//Usar información de Login contra el servicio REST
$request = new http\Client\Request("GET", SERVICE_URL."/login", ["Auth" => $_POST['user'].":".$_POST['pass']]);
$request->setOptions(["timeout"=>1]);
$client = new http\Client;
$client->enqueue($request)->send();
//$response=$client->getResponse();
//echo $response->getResponseCode();
```

Both user connection to this port and server connection to the port I am trying to contact via SERVICE_URL require https. But when I attempt to send the form to this page, my browser outputs a "Reset Connection" error, and refuses to go on as it supposes it is unsafe.

Why is this happening? Can PHP not keep more than one socket open and thus it has to close one to open the other one? How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the other server really runnning on port 444? Default https port is 443. If this is correct, it might be that if your server uses a self signed ssl cert, your php client might refuse it.

Comment: Yeah the server is running on 444. The port the other service SERVICE_URL is using 443. Still, I've checked the apache logs and the php interpreter seems to be having a segmentation fault, which leads me to thinking that the php module has a bug. I'm going to test older versions of the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked. Apparently version 2.5.1 of the pecl_http extension module has a bug. This works totally fine on version 2.5.0. I'm letting the developer know.

Comment: The developer said he could not reproduce the issue, but this is the only way I can get it to work on  my system.